# Proper way to extract part of class in order to use it in framework

Tags: swift, share-extension

I am creating a share extension for my iOS app. I am going to create an embedded framework to share my code between me app and extension.

But I want to let extension to only be aware of code that it needs. The problem is that I already have classes with a lot of field (and many of them are not required in extension).

Here is an example. I have a User class:

```
class User {
    var name: String
    var badge: UserBadge?
}
```

In the example above: I only need "name" property in extension, and i DON'T need userBadge property there.

I could include "UserBadge" class to framework, but it is not a good solution, because as a result I will have a lot of unnecessary classes in framework.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. First of all I tried using Swift extensions. But they don't allow having Stored Properties. So this does not help.
2. The second possible solution is creating a base "User" class with "name" property only. And also creating an inherited class "AppUser" that has "userBadge" field. Thus we could use "AppUser" class in application and use "User" class in framework. This solution will make me rewrite all my classes.

Is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you already marked properties as `internal` versus `public`? Because that seems like it would accomplish what you're looking to do.